# How Registration free activation of COM dll is different inside c# dll and vc++ dll?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, activex, registration, regfreecom

I am new in Registration free activation of COM dll, few days back i posted one question on Reg free inside c# application and i was able to successfully done.

Now looking forward i have two different requirement as following

- Can we use Registration free activation of COM dll inside c# dll
  (classlibrary project)?
- Can we use Registration free activation of COM dll inisde VC++ dll
  project?

Is there any difference of implementation of Registration free COM inside c# dll and vc++ dll?
Because i have done in c# window application where i just set Isolated property of COM as true and automatically VS has generate manifest for application with respect of COM dll

I am using VS2010 in development machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of registration for .NET DLL. The NET Runtime handles (facilitates) it for you. 
Even for VC++, if you are using .NET as developement platform, you need not to worry about registration of DLL.

If you are using native DLL, and are exposing component via COM, you need to register the DLL. For this, you may use `regsrv32.exe` tool to register. The DLL must export `DllRegisterServer` for registration, and `DllUnregisterServer` for de-registration.